# How can I find additional files installed with my python package from an included script?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I've built a python package that installs with a number of external files. I need to be able to read those files from a script that gets installed with the package. I can see that I can use `__file__` inside my script, and it returns something like this:

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/M5-0.3.0-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/..
```

and so I can navigate to where the files were installed (top level of the .egg directory), but I'm looking for a more "standard" way to determine where my package is installed.

Answer (score 2):

You might want something like the 
[`pkgutil.get_data`](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) function.

It will read in resources relative to `__file__` if your package lives as a standard python package directory structure on the disk, and I think it will read resources out of a zipped egg as well (though I've not used it for that myself).

Answer (score 1):

does `os.getcwd()` get you anywhere close? (it returns the 'current working directory', usually the one from which you lauched the main script)

what would be wrong with using `__file__`? If you are looking for any higher level function, it would probably use a similar technique.

```
import os
d = os.path.dirname(__file__[:__file__.rindex(os.extsep+'egg')])
```

gives you the directory; 'navigate' to it with

```
os.startfile(d)
```